# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when submiting a Apple Pay payload to process

Tags: swift, applepay

I'm working in a app that uses Apple Pay, and everything was working, but suddenly this crash start to happen

```
func startPaymentWith(output: PaymentHandlerResponseProtocol?) {
    self.output = output
    self.output?.startProcess()
    // Create our payment request
    let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummaryItems
    paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "abcde.abcdef"
    paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
    paymentRequest.countryCode = "BR"
    paymentRequest.currencyCode = "BRL"
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = self.supportedNetworks
    
    
    print("comoestaovalorsemreplace \(paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems[0].amount)")
    // Display our payment request
    paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest) // Here happens the EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    paymentController?.delegate = self
    paymentController?.present(completion: { (presented: Bool) in
        if presented {
            debugPrint("Presented payment controller")
        } else {
            debugPrint("Failed to present payment controller")
            self.output?.responseWith(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

This is shown in var paymentRequest when mouse pointer is hover above the   the variable:

expression produced error: error: /var/folders/sp/8x6rp88s4nv6s3z1635pqdtm0000gq/T/expr139-c248cd..swift:1:65: error: cannot find type 'PassKit' in scope
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<PassKit.PKPaymentRequest>(bitPattern: 0x15e4e9da0)!.pointee)

Comment: Where does a guy named 'PaymentHandlerResponseProtocol' come from?

Comment: 'startProcess'?  Where does it come from?

Comment: Hello @ElTomato this guy is responsable to block the main screen with a wait message (startProcess), and is responsible to handle the request's  response (responseWith). Well in resume, it is the ViewController.